# No system tray icon of Steam

Tags: release-loki, steam

On Loki **Steam** have no system tray icon. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove steam from /etc/wingpanel.d/ayatana.blacklist

Comment: Thx, it solve the problem!!!

Comment: any workaround for other apps like Insync?

Comment: but why is steam even on this blacklist?

Answer (score 0):

There was a simple solution in Freya, it dates back in 2013, if someone ma want to check the article is [here](http://elementarytips.blogspot.it/2013/05/steam-icons-for-elementary-os.html)